# 100% packet loss when connected to new router wirelessly

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.10

I just bought a new router, a TP-LINK TL-WR1043ND V2.1, and I have an issue with it. To be frank, I don't know if it's a problem of the router or my computer, that's why I'm posting this here.

The router generally works fine: every other device can connect to it without any problem, even my laptop can connect to it through ethernet cable, the problem only occurs if I try to connect via Wi-fi. Then what happens is my laptop gets connected to the router, and for a few (2-3) seconds I can reach the router, but then suddenly all packets are dropped, no matter what I am trying to connect to. The strange thing is that my laptop says I am still connected to the network.

I didn't have any issue with the old router, which was a TP-Link TL-WR542G.

I tried disabling the 802.11n protocol on the router, but it didn't help.

The output of wireless_script is the following:

```
> ########## wireless info START ##########
> 
> Report from: 18 Jan 2015 11:42 CET +0100
> 
> Booted last: 18 Jan 2015 10:42 CET +0100
> 
> Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000
> 
> ##### release ###########################
> 
> Distributor ID:   Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 14.10 Release:   14.10
> Codename: utopic
> 
> ##### kernel ############################
> 
> Linux 3.16.0-29-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 15 22:27:29 UTC 2014
> x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> 
> Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7
> 
> ##### desktop ###########################
> 
> Lubuntu
> 
> ##### lspci #############################
> 
> 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260
> [8086:08b2] (rev 73)  Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260
> [8086:4262]   Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
> 
> ##### lsusb #############################
> 
> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.  Bus 001 Device 001: ID
> 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub Bus 003 Device 001: ID
> 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus 002 Device 004: ID
> 8087:07dc Intel Corp.  Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:0538 Acer, Inc  Bus
> 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> 
> ##### PCMCIA card info ##################
> 
> 'pccardctl' is not installed (package "pcmciautils").
> 
> ##### rfkill ############################
> 
> 0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN     Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no 1:
> ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth  Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no 2:
> hci0: Bluetooth   Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no 3: phy0: Wireless
> LAN   Soft blocked: no    Hard blocked: no
> 
> ##### lsmod #############################
> 
> iwlmvm                217797  0  mac80211              660592  1
> iwlmvm iwlwifi               183038  1 iwlmvm cfg80211             
> 510218  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm wmi                    19193  0 
> ideapad_laptop         18278  0  sparse_keymap          13948  1
> ideapad_laptop
> 
> ##### interfaces ########################
> 
> auto lo iface lo inet loopback
> 
> ##### ifconfig ##########################
> 
> wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>  
>           inet addr:192.168.0.104  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>           inet6 addr: fe80::fef8:aeff:fea1:419/64 Scope:Link
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:1474 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:1274 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>           RX bytes:372696 (372.6 KB)  TX bytes:384314 (384.3 KB)
> 
> ##### iwconfig ##########################
> 
> lo        no wireless extensions.
> 
> wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"SajtosPogi"  
>           Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: <MAC 'SajtosPogi' [AC1]>   
>           Bit Rate=11 Mb/s   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
>           Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
>           Power Management:on
>           Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-36 dBm  
>           Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
>           Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:24   Missed beacon:0
> 
> ##### route #############################
> 
> Kernel IP routing table Destination     Gateway         Genmask       
> Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
> 0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
> 192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
> 
> ##### resolv.conf #######################
> 
> nameserver 127.0.1.1
> 
> ##### nm-tool ###########################
> 
> NetworkManager Tool
> 
> State: connected (global)
> 
> - Device: wlan0  [SajtosPogi] --------------------------------------------------   Type:              802.11 WiFi   Driver:            iwlwifi   State:             connected   Default:           yes   HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0'
> [IF]>
> 
>   Capabilities:
>     Speed:           11 Mb/s
> 
>   Wireless Properties
>     WEP Encryption:  yes
>     WPA Encryption:  yes
>     WPA2 Encryption: yes
> 
>   Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
>     *SajtosPogi:     Infra, <MAC 'SajtosPogi' [AC1]>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 84 WPA WPA2
> 
>   IPv4 Settings:
>     Address:         192.168.0.104
>     Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
>     Gateway:         192.168.0.1
> 
>     DNS:             192.168.0.1
> 
> ##### NetworkManager.state ##############
> 
> [main] NetworkingEnabled=true WirelessEnabled=true WWANEnabled=true
> WimaxEnabled=true
> 
> ##### NetworkManager.conf ###############
> 
> [main] plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono dns=dnsmasq
> 
> [ifupdown] managed=false
> 
> ##### NetworkManager profiles ###########
> 
> [[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SajtosPogi]] (600 root)
> [connection] id=SajtosPogi | type=802-11-wireless [802-11-wireless]
> ssid=SajtosPogi [ipv4] method=auto [ipv6] method=auto
> 
> ##### iw reg get ########################
> 
> 'iw' is not installed (package "iw").
> 
> ##### iwlist channels ###################
> 
> lo        no frequency information.
> 
> wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
>           Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
>           Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
>           Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
>           Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
>           Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
>           Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
>           Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
>           Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
>           Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
>           Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
>           Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
>           Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
>           Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
>           Current Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
> 
> ##### iwlist scan #######################
> 
> Channel occupancy:
> 
>       1   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
> 
> lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.
> 
> wlan0     Scan completed :
>           Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'SajtosPogi' [AC1]>
>                     Channel:9
>                     Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
>                     Quality=70/70  Signal level=-27 dBm  
>                     Encryption key:on
>                     ESSID:"SajtosPogi"
>                     Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
>                               9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
>                     Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
>                     Mode:Master
>                     Extra:tsf=00000000b06498ab
>                     Extra: Last beacon: 80ms ago
>                     IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
>                         Group Cipher : CCMP
>                         Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
>                         Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
>                     IE: WPA Version 1
>                         Group Cipher : CCMP
>                         Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
>                         Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
> 
> ##### module infos ######################
> 
> [iwlmvm] filename:      
> /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
> license:        GPL author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel
> Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com> version:        in-tree:
> description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
> srcversion:     DF2B4108DD59AC2EC4C7D5B depends:       
> iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211 intree:         Y vermagic:      
> 3.16.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload modversions  signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key sig_key:       
> 70:63:7F:DE:89:46:26:78:AF:F2:D9:C2:BB:12:90:BE:2F:ED:1F:B1
> sig_hashalgo:   sha512 parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug
> an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool) parm:          
> power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low
> power, default: 2 (int)
> 
> [mac80211] filename:      
> /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
> license:        GPL description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem srcversion: 
> B3A65EB1DAE59CB6B5FD971 depends:        cfg80211 intree:         Y
> vermagic:       3.16.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload modversions  signer: 
> Magrathea: Glacier signing key sig_key:       
> 70:63:7F:DE:89:46:26:78:AF:F2:D9:C2:BB:12:90:BE:2F:ED:1F:B1
> sig_hashalgo:   sha512 parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum
> nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int) parm:        
> max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4).
> (int) parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals
> before we decide beacon was lost. (int) parm:          
> probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before
> disconnecting (reason 4). (int) parm:          
> ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211
> to use (charp)
> 
> [iwlwifi] filename:      
> /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
> license:        GPL author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel
> Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com> version:        in-tree:
> description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux firmware:     
> iwlwifi-100-5.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode firmware:    
> iwlwifi-135-6.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode firmware:     
> iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode firmware:   
> iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode firmware:   
> iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
> firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode firmware:      
> iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode firmware:   
> iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode firmware:   
> iwlwifi-8000-8.ucode srcversion:     D335B9FC08B25C4ADA0BD33 depends: 
> cfg80211 intree:         Y vermagic:       3.16.0-29-generic SMP
> mod_unload modversions  signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
> sig_key:       
> 70:63:7F:DE:89:46:26:78:AF:F2:D9:C2:BB:12:90:BE:2F:ED:1F:B1
> sig_hashalgo:   sha512 parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in
> software (default 0 [hardware]) (int) parm:          
> 11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg
> TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint) parm:          
> amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int) parm:          
> fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
> parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB
> (defualt: 0 dB) (int) parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue
> watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int) parm:   
> nvm_file:NVM file name (charp) parm:           uapsd_disable:disable
> U-APSD functionality (default: N) (bool) parm:          
> bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool) parm: 
> led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off
> (default: 0) (int) parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power
> management (default: disable) (bool) parm:          
> power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1)
> (int) parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW
> (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)
> 
> [cfg80211] filename:      
> /lib/modules/3.16.0-29-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
> description:    wireless configuration support license:        GPL
> author:         Johannes Berg srcversion:     DEE8EAA48495E392CD51C2D
> depends:         intree:         Y vermagic:       3.16.0-29-generic
> SMP mod_unload modversions  signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing
> key sig_key:       
> 70:63:7F:DE:89:46:26:78:AF:F2:D9:C2:BB:12:90:BE:2F:ED:1F:B1
> sig_hashalgo:   sha512 parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11
> regulatory domain code (charp) parm:          
> cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band
> (bool)
> 
> ##### module parameters #################
> 
> [iwlmvm] init_dbg: N power_scheme: 2
> 
> [mac80211] beacon_loss_count: 7 ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
> max_nullfunc_tries: 2 max_probe_tries: 5 probe_wait_ms: 500
> 
> [iwlwifi] 11n_disable: 0 amsdu_size_8K: 0 antenna_coupling: 0
> bt_coex_active: Y fw_monitor: N fw_restart: Y led_mode: 0 nvm_file:
> (null) power_level: 0 power_save: N swcrypto: 0 uapsd_disable: N
> wd_disable: 1
> 
> [cfg80211] cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N ieee80211_regdom: 00
> 
> ##### /etc/modules ######################
> 
> ##### modprobe options ##################
> 
> [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf] blacklist ath_pci
> 
> [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf] blacklist evbug blacklist usbmouse
> blacklist usbkbd blacklist eepro100 blacklist de4x5 blacklist eth1394
> blacklist snd_intel8x0m blacklist snd_aw2 blacklist i2c_i801 blacklist
> prism54 blacklist bcm43xx blacklist garmin_gps blacklist asus_acpi
> blacklist snd_pcsp blacklist pcspkr blacklist amd76x_edac
> 
> [/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf] alias net-pf-3 off alias
> net-pf-6 off alias net-pf-9 off alias net-pf-11 off alias net-pf-12
> off alias net-pf-19 off alias net-pf-21 off alias net-pf-36 off
> 
> [/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf] remove iwlwifi \ (/sbin/lsmod | grep -o
> -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \ && /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
> 
> [/etc/modprobe.d/libpisock9.conf] blacklist visor
> 
> [/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf] softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en
> 
> [/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf] options cirrus modeset=1 options
> mgag200 modeset=1
> 
> ##### rc.local ##########################
> 
> exit 0
> 
> ##### pm-utils ##########################
> 
> ##### udev rules ########################
> 
> [/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
> # PCI device 0x8086:0x08b2 (iwlwifi) SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF]>",
> ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
> # USB device 0x:0x (r8188eu) SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0",
> ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"
> # USB device 0x:0x (asix) SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0",
> ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
> 
> ##### dmesg #############################
> 
> [ 3575.863041] wlan0: deauthenticating from <MAC 'SajtosPogi' [AC1]>
> by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING) [ 3578.738726] iwlwifi
> 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Enabled (repeated 2 times) [
> 3578.751343] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready [ 3579.498005] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC 'SajtosPogi' [AC1]> [ 3579.500043] wlan0: send auth to <MAC 'SajtosPogi' [AC1]> (try 1/3) [ 3579.502946] wlan0: authenticated [ 3579.504258] wlan0: associate with <MAC 'SajtosPogi' [AC1]> (try 1/3) [ 3579.514395] wlan0: RX AssocResp
> from <MAC 'SajtosPogi' [AC1]> (capab=0x31 status=0 aid=4) [
> 3579.515392] wlan0: associated [ 3579.515419] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
> 
> ########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: You can indent all that terminal output with four spaces (or select it and hit the `{}` icon) to make it all nice and preformatted.

Answer (score 1):

Installing OpenWrt on the router solved the problem.

Comment: Will you mind elaborating the answer focusing on _how_ part?